# Python: Self as attribute

Tags: python, methods, self

My problem is : When I test my "isProduct" method, i get the error message saying:

```
TypeError: isProduct() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

So, I looked for this problem, and I found I had to add 'self' before calling my method. I did. But still, it says :

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Don't mind what the methods say, my problem concerns the attributes, class and self.
Here is my code, what am I doing (very) wrong ?

```
import xlrd
wb=xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Inputs_UNF_newForm.xlsx')
s=wb.sheet_by_name('Chemical treatments')
p=wb.sheet_by_name('Products')

class World:


 def RowMatrix(self,sheet_name,matrix_name):
    sheet=wb.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
    number_of_rows = sheet.nrows

    for row in range(number_of_rows):
        value  = str((sheet.cell(row,0).value))

        if value == "#" +matrix_name:
            start=row

        if value !="":
            end=row+1

    return (start,end)


 def isProduct(self,look_for):

    (start,end)= World.RowMatrix("Products","Products")
    number_of_columns=p.ncols

    for row in range(start,end):
        for col in range(number_of_columns):
            value  = str((sheet.cell(row,col).value))
            if value == look_for:
                return true
            else:
                return false


 if self.isProduct("K20"):
    print("true")
 else:
    print("false")
```

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) about classes and objects in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted you need to create an instance of your `World` class to access it outside of the class. And inside the class you normally should access it via `self`, not via the class name. So

```
(start,end)= World.RowMatrix("Products","Products")
```

probably should be

```
start, end = self.RowMatrix("Products", "Products")
```

However the `isProduct()` method may not do what you want it to, since it returns after it's processed the first column of the first row.

It's normal in Python to initialize a class (when necessary) using its `__init__()` method. This is explained in the official Python docs [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) and in the tutorial linked by André Laszlo in the comments to your question.

---

Rather than doing

```
if value == look_for:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

simply do

```
return value == look_for
```

I didn't mention this earlier, because I suspected that the logic in `isProduct()` was wrong, since the `return` statement means that the method breaks out of those nested `for` loops after it tests the first `value`.

Comment: I just corrected the `return`problem in my `isProduct()` method, and the calling of the method inside the class. But when I test `isProduct()` with an `if`, it says `NameError: global name 'true' is not defined`. Any idea?

Comment: @AmyMagoria: Sure! It's `True` with a capital `T`; similarly `False`. But there's a better way to do that. See the example I've added above.

Answer (score 2):

You need an instance of "World" to access the methods from outside that class:

```
w = World()
if w.isProduct("K20"):
   #Do something
```

Answer (score 2):

You have created a class with an instance method but have not instantiated the class. try it like so:

```
my_instance = World()
print(my_instance.isProduct("K20"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your last "if" bit of code doesn't belong to any def you have because of wrong indentation,that is if that is meant to be inside your class. Otherwise you need to instantiate you class into a variable to hold a reference (don't use self keyword from outside the class body)